# Add Docker to ABP Framework Project

Tags: c#, .net, abp

I'm trying to add Docker To ABP Project  .

i have tried to follow the documentation but it referencing files that i can't find in my project.

the name of the file is ** build-images-locally.ps1**

is there is a tutorial for beginners or a book to understand how to avoid such problems with the abp framework

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different ABP templates, one of them is open-source and other one is the commercial template. You can check the difference at https://docs.abp.io/en/commercial/latest/abp-framework-vs-abp-commercial.

Docker support is available in only commercial templates. But you can dockerize your open-source template easily aswell since it is a typical .NET application.

Here is a very simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0
COPY bin/Release/net8.0/publish/ app/
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProjectName.Web.dll"]
```

that will copy the published files to your image.
To populate the `bin/Release/net8.0/publish` folder, simply navigate under your Web project and run:

```
dotnet publish -c Release
docker build -t mycompanyname/myapplication-web:latest .
```

The **build-images-locally.ps1** script does the similar functionality in a powershell script.